# How to use BindingSource with not 1 to 1 set of columns between the list and the DataGridView

Tags: datagridview

I have the following situation working with winforms:

1. I defined a DataGridView with X columns.
2. Bind it to a list containing X-1 columns

   dataGridViewMain.DataSource = _bindingSource;
   _bindingSource.DataSource = _currentMediaItems;
3. After a while I update the list and when performing the following call:
   _bindingSource.DataSource = _currentMediaItems;
   I get the following error : "At least one of the DataGridView control's columns has no cell template."

Someone can help with a workaround?

thanks!